# Extra space on left side of Bootstrap carousel's left arrow control

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/xwVvZJ

Here's a screenshot of the issue: https://gyazo.com/0c59df7f083c6427818a68de23eb513e

Here's the inserted code for convenience:

```css
 html, body
 {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
 }

 .carousel-inner > .item > img
 {
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
   }
 
 .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right
 {
  background: none !important;
  filter: progid: none !important;
  outline: 0;
  }
 .carousel:hover .carousel-control
 {
    visibility: visible;
 }
 
 .chiz-slide1 { background:url("http://www.designerspics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/origami_windmill_free_photo-690x457.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; }
 .chiz-slide2 { background:url("http://www.designerspics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/boats_3_free_photo-690x457.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; }
 
 .chiz-slide1, .chiz-slide2
 {
  height:100vh;
  background-size:cover;
 }
 
 div#carol
 {
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
 }
 
 /*select the <a> element that uses both the "carousel-control" AND "left" class*/
 a[href="#carol"]
 {
  width:5rem;
  height:5rem;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
 }
 a[href="#carol"].left
 {
  left:3%;
 }
 a[href="#carol"].right
 {
  right:3%;
 }
 
 a[href="#carol"] .glyphicon-chevron-left:before, a[href="#carol"] .glyphicon-chevron-right:before
 {
  outline:1px solid black;
       /*Reset the icon*/
       content: " ";
    
       /*Give layout*/    
       display:block;
    
       /*Your image as background*/
    background:url("http://www.Oneniceday.com/Left.png") no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
       
    /*To show full image set the dimensions*/
    width:5rem;
    height:5rem;
   }
   
   a[href="#carol"] .glyphicon-chevron-right:before
   {
    background:url("http://www.Oneniceday.com/Right.png") no-repeat;
       background-size:cover;
    /*To show full image set the dimensions*/
    width:5rem;
    height:5rem;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         <div id="carol" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            
             <!--wrapper for indicators-->
             <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                 <li data-target="#carol" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carol" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                
                <!--wrapper for images-->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                 <div class="item active chiz-slide1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item chiz-slide2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carol" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carol" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `top` and `left` of your glyphicons are being offset by 50% of their container (i.e. 25 px).

This will keep your glyphicons consistent with the positioning of their containing anchor tags:

```
#carol a.carousel-control span {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tks! It works now, though I'm still not sure why the container of the glyphicons (the span element, in this case) are being offset by 50%. In my code, the transform-Y part only applies to the element vertically, not horizontally. Maybe Bootstrap somehow adds some space to the span elements? Tks!

Comment: From what I can tell, the CSS originates from bootstrap's bootstrap.min.css file. Also, keep in mind that the transform-Y isn't necessarily going to counteract bootstrap's styles since they might not be referring to the same contexts. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You had 3% left and right for icons.

You can adjust However you want.

```
a[href="#carol"].left
    {
        left:0px;
    }
    a[href="#carol"].right
    {
        right:20px;
    }
```

**[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvjZyP)**